Cannot start maven from wrapper
execute the following command:
mvn wrapper:wrapper

Part of the output information:
[INFO] --- wrapper:3.3.2:wrapper (default-cli) @ parent ---
[INFO] Unpacked only-script type wrapper distribution org.apache.maven.wrapper:maven-wrapper-distribution:zip:only-script:3.3.2
[INFO] Configuring .mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties to use Maven 3.9.8 and download from https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried using maven wrapper:
>mvnw.cmd -v
Cannot start maven from wrapper

I found that the mvn wrapper:wrapper command did not generate a maven-wrapper.jar file in the .mvn/wrapper directory, it's only maven-wrapper.properties:
wrapperVersion=3.3.2
distributionType=only-script
distributionUrl=https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.9.8/apache-maven-3.9.8-bin.zip

What did I miss?

I was seeing the error "Cannot start maven from wrapper" this morning after I try running .\mvnw.cmd in a demo spring boot application. Here the problem was that my local .m2 repository path had a space in it, like C:\Users\My User\.m2. Probably you get this error because of it.
It seams that mvnw.cmd is not working properly if the local repository path has a space.
The workaround that solved this issue for me was to set the "MAVEN_USER_HOME" environment variable with a path that has no space in it like : C:\Windows\temp\.m2. After setting this environment variable, you should close and reopen the terminal ou IDE your working with to load it so that mvnw.cmd can read it.
